# sqlalchemy change with executemany from version 0.5 to 0.7

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert

I'm attempting to collect up a list of dictionaries, and do a bulk insert into a mysql db with sqlalchemy.

According to [these docs for version 0.5](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_5/sqlexpression.html#executing-multiple-statements), you do this with an `executemany` function call off of a `connection` object. This is the only place where I've been able to find that `executemany` exists.

However, in [these docs for 0.7](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements), I find that even though executemany is referenced, they *do not use it in the code snippet*, and in fact, it no longer exists in the `connection` class.

It seems that the two functions were combined, but if so, how is the `connection.execute` method different from the `session.execute` method? It seems in the docs that `session.execute` does not support bulk inserts, so how would one go about inserting several thousand dictionaries into a single table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misreading the 0.5 link, the example you're pointing to still uses "execute()".  SQLAlchemy has never exposed an explicit executemany() method.   executemany() is specifically a function of the *underlying DBAPI*, which SQLAlchemy will make use of if the given parameter set is detected as a list of parameters.

`session.execute()` supports the same functionality as `connection.execute()`, except the parameter list is given using the named argument "params".   The docstring isn't explicit about this which should likely be adjusted.

You can also get a transaction-specific `Connection` object from the `Session` using the `session.connection()` method.

Comment: You are correct, it is supposed to use the execute many method. However, mysqldb has a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3511137&group_id=22307&atid=374932) in it, that I ran into. I've attempted to migrate to oursql, but no luck so far.

Comment: A quick update in case anyone else sees this, from what I've seen [here](https://bitbucket.org/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/src/40976cb8c827/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/oursql.py), the oursql wrapper in sqlalchemy does not actually seem to support executemany. *Oursql does*, but sqlalchemy does not set it up correctly it seems.